# Replace each character of the word by the number of uppercase characters in this word

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I want to achieve multiple word support.

E.g. abc AAAA cbAAaa => 000 4444 222222

For now all the program does is first word conversion.

As from debugger in Mars simulator it seems that it's doing all the loops correctly. Same for values of registers. (Maybe I'm missing something)
I assume that words need to be shorter than 10 chars.

If anyone can spot a mistake I would be grateful.
Also if you have any tips to debugging this or code improvements, feel free to say.

My code:

```
    .data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a string: "
msgout: .asciiz "Output string: "
input:  .space  256
output: .space  256
    .text
    .globl main

main:
    li  $v0, 4          # Print enter a string prompt
    la  $a0, prompt     
    syscall

    li  $v0, 8          # Ask the user for the string they want to reverse
    la  $a0, input      # We'll store it in 'input'
    li  $a1, 256        # Only 256 chars/bytes allowed
    syscall

    la  $t2, ($a0)      # t2 - input string

    word:
        li  $t1, 0              # Normal counter
        li  $t5, 0              # Uppercase counter
        li  $t6, 0              # First letter of word
        j   word_countUppercase
        word_precountUppercase:
            addi    $t1, $t1, 1             # Add 1 to index to avoid space in next word
            la  $t6, ($t1)              # Set t6 to the first index of t2 (start of word)
            la  $t5, 0                  # $t5 - 0
        word_countUppercase:
            #addi   $t1, $t1, $t7
            add $t3, $t2, $t1               # $t2 is the base address for our 'input' array, add loop index
            lb  $t4, 0($t3)             # load a byte at a time according to counter

            beq     $t4, ' ', word_prereplace       # We found end of word
            bltu    $t4, ' ', word_prereplace       # We found end of string    

            addi    $t1, $t1, 1             # Advance our counter (i++)

            bltu    $t4, 'A', word_countUppercase
            bgtu    $t4, 'Z', word_countUppercase

            addi    $t5, $t5, 1                 # Advance our counter (i++)
            j   word_countUppercase

        word_prereplace:
            la  $t2, ($a0)              # t2 - input string
            la  $t1, ($t6)              # Normal counter
            addi $t5, $t5, '0'

            word_replace:
                add $t3, $t2, $t1           # $t2 is the base address for our 'input' array, add loop index
                lb  $t4, 0($t3)         # load a byte at a time according to counter    

                beq $t4, ' ', word_replaceExit  # end of the word
                bltu    $t4, ' ', exit          # We found end of string    

                sb  $t5, output($t1)        # Overwrite this byte address in memory 

                addi    $t1, $t1, 1             # Advance our counter (i++)
                j   word_replace
            word_replaceExit:
                j   word_precountUppercase



exit:
    li  $v0, 4          # Print msgout
    la  $a0, msgout
    syscall

    li  $v0, 4          # Print the output string!
    la  $a0, output
    syscall

    li  $v0, 10         # exit()
    syscall
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: answer to original question was, that the original code did fill in output buffer only bytes corresponding to words' content, but kept undefined memory between, which happens to be zeroed in MARS simulator, so there was accidentally zero-terminator after first word, and the "print string" service of MARS does expect zero-terminated strings = only first word was printed.

---

Here is my variant for the same task, using various shortcuts to do the same thing in (marginally) fewer instructions (it's still O(N) complexity).

Also I wrote it in a way to make sure inputs with multiple spaces, starting/ending with space or empty input work correctly (for "two spaces" on input it will output also "two spaces") (I didn't test all of these with your original code, so I'm not saying there is some bug, seems it should handle most of them well, I just did test thoroughly only my variant):

```bash
# delayed branching should be OFF
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter a string: "
msgout: .asciiz "Output string: "
input:  .space  256
output: .space  256
    .text
    .globl main

main:
    li  $v0, 4          # Print enter a string prompt
    la  $a0, prompt
    syscall

    li  $v0, 8          # Ask the user for the string they want to reverse
    la  $a0, input      # We'll store it in 'input'
    li  $a1, 256        # Only 256 chars/bytes allowed
    syscall

    la    $a1, output
    # a0 = input, a1 = output
new_word:
    move  $t0, $zero    # t0 word length = 0
    li    $t1, '0'      # t1 uppercase counter = '0' (ASCII counter)
word_parse_loop:
    lbu   $t2, ($a0)    # next input character
    addi  $a0, $a0, 1   # advance input pointer
    bltu  $t2, 33, word_done   # end of word detected (space or newline)
      # "less than 33" to get shorter code than for "less/equal than 32"
    addi  $t0, $t0, 1   # ++word length
    # check if word character is uppercase letter
    addiu $t2, $t2, -65 # subtract 'A' => makes t2 = 0..25 for 'A'..'Z'
    sltiu $t3, $t2, 26  # t3 = (t2 < 26) ? 1 : 0
    add   $t1, $t1, $t3 # ++uppercase counter if uppercase detected
    j     word_parse_loop

word_output_fill:
    # loop to fill output with uppercase-counter (entry is "word_done" below)
    sb    $t1, ($a1)
    addi  $a1, $a1, 1
    addiu $t0, $t0, -1
word_done:
    # t0 = word length, t1 = uppercase ASCII counter, t2 = space, newline or less
    # a0 = next word (or beyond data), a1 = output pointer (to be written to)
    bnez  $t0, word_output_fill

    bltu  $t2, ' ', it_was_last_word
    # t2 == space, move onto next word in input (store space also in output)
    sb    $t2, ($a1)
    addi  $a1, $a1, 1
    j     new_word

it_was_last_word:
    # finish output data by storing zero terminator
    sb    $zero, ($a1)

    # output result
    li  $v0, 4          # Print msgout
    la  $a0, msgout
    syscall

    li  $v0, 4          # Print the output string!
    la  $a0, output
    syscall

    li  $v0, 10         # exit()
    syscall
```

Things to note ("tricks"?):

- the uppercase counter is starting at value 48 (character for zero), so the "counter" does hold ASCII digit whole time (for less-than-10 count, for 10+ it will go to other characters beyond digits) and is ready to be written into string without any conversion (because the counter is not used as "integer" anywhere, you can optimize out the conversion like this).
- it's advancing through input and output in sequential way, never reading some input twice or readjusting input/output position, so algorithm like this can work also with "stream"-like data (it almost does produce 1:1 output for every input character, except the output is slightly delayed "per word", i.e. it will process input stream until "end of word", then whole output word is produced (this architecture may be important with some I/O like magnetic tapes on input, and serial printer on output).
- the check for A..Z uppercase letter range does use only single compare condition (the letter 'A' is subtracted from character first, normalizing the value into 0..25 for uppercase letters, everything else, when treated as unsigned integer must be of greater value than 25, so single `< 26` test is enough to detect all uppercase letters.
- the uppercase counter is updated every time, by adding either 0 or 1 (depending on the previously mentioned condition), which avoid extra branching in the code. Generally modern CPUs like more non-branching code, as they may more aggressively cache/speculate ahead, so in cases where the chances for branch is more like 50%, non-branching variant of code has usually better performance (for cases where branch is like 5-10% chance, branching away on that uncommon condition and staying in line for common case, may be better, i.e. things like "end of word" branches).

Or if you have any other question about particular part of code, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I was having empty spaces in my output so the string was: 111[]222[]1111 and print was doing it to first empty space so 111 only.

To fix it I have added this code: (before word label)

```
li  $t1, 0                  # Normal counter
    rewriteoutput:
        add $t3, $t2, $t1           # $t2 is the base address for our 'input' array, add loop index
        lb  $t4, 0($t3)         # load a byte at a time according to counter

        bltu    $t4, ' ', word          # We found end of string

        sb  $t4, output($t1)        # Overwrite this byte address in memory
        addi    $t1, $t1, 1             # Advance our counter (i++)
        j rewriteoutput
```

I know that we can probably do it in better way, but cannot understand why I can't do

```
sw $a0, output
```

instead of it (Error at runtime: Runtime exception at 0x0040002c: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x10010121)

Comment: it was not "empty space", it was zero, and the `syscall` for "print string" is expecting zero-terminated string, so it did print only first three characters. I don't understand what `sw $a0, output` should do and where, but obviously `output` address is not word-aligned, so you can't store word there, but I don't know what you want to achieve with it?

Comment: so is there any shorter way of I just wrote? Or I have to do it manually as I did in output rewriting?

Comment: Shorter way of what exactly? I don't see how `sw $a0, output` relates to your other stuff, that would store current word value (32 bits) in `a0` to memory starting at address `output`, which is char buffer, so storing 32 bit word there is like writing four characters at same time (but it will fail because word writes require word-aligned memory address). Your fix to write space between words in output is correct one, but your overall code is quite convoluted and complex and can be done in considerably fewer instructions. But that takes months/years of experience. I'll try to post my version.

Comment: I mean, your solution is very reasonable for somebody just learning, and for their first working version. Also it reads quite well and seems like it follows some idea and it's not just random mess of adding instructions until "it works", but trying to stay "to the point". And my point is to not stop there (first working version), and keep experimenting a bit more, if you can find different ways of writing the same task. Once you are solid in basics, asm may be quite fun, figuring out different concepts and tricks, how the same thing can be done (at least I love it).